# Constraints not showing up in Xcode 6.3 even though I added them

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, constraints

I am working on constraints with auto layout. On some view controllers it is fine, but on others, when I add constraints, they don't really add I think? For example, in the ones that seem to be working, when I click on an element, like a UITextView, on the right, I can select each of the constraints and edit them accordingly. But when I do the same for another view controller, the constraints don't appear, to be edited. 1st picture is whats wrong. 2nd picture is whats right. How do I get the first to do the same as the second...?

[image: Here is an example of what is happening]
[image: Compared to this]

Comment: check height and width of your text field. sometimes after applying auto-layout  hieght and with automatically set to zero. so , please check it once.

Comment: @BadalShah That does not seem to be the problem. I checked and it is normal.

Comment: @AnthonySaltarelli have you been able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I faced a similar problem today, and it appears to be a bug with XCode (I'm using version 6.4). I was able to solve this by restarting XCode.

If that doesn't work either, try cleaning your project (cmd + shift + k) and then restart XCode.